# Invalid Certificate Warning When Linking Two Sites Together

Tags: http, ssl, github, https, ssl-certificate

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem, but the closest answers say to delete the "Cert High that expires Nov. 2031", which I tried, but had no positive effect. I've contacted both Github and Namecheap and neither know what is causing the problem.

I have two websites (johnwolfe.io and johnwolfe.tech) that are linked to each other (they are run through Github and have a custom domain and hosting through Namecheap). When I click on a link from one site to another I always get a certificate warning:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuEtF.png Screenshot of connection warning

For instance, if I go to www.johnwolfe.tech and click on the link to www.johnwolfe.io the warning appears. Similarly, if I go to www.johnwolfe.io and click on Resume, which is the link to www.johnwolfe.tech the warning also appears.

I've tried removing the custom domain portion of the Resume site and just using the git hosted version, but that still creates a certificate warning when I go to johnwolfe.io. I also checked to see if any certificates were expired and they were all up-to-date.

I would really appreciate any insight anyone has, as I've searched all over the Internet and asked both companies and have hit a dead end in all situations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with linking the sites together. Simply entering the URL `https://www.johnwolfe.io/` or `https://www.johnwolfe.tech/` will already result in this error because the certificate for this site is for github.com and not for your domain.

I don't think that github supports https on custom domains (except domains like  `some-user.github.com`). [Searching for this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+custom+domain+https) suggests that you might get this feature by putting Cloudflare SSL in front of github.

Comment: Github pages specifically says it doesn't do HTTPS. Additionally, the only way you can share a single cert between properties is if they are all in the same domain but use different subdomains (called a wildcard cert). What you are looking to do - same cert, different domains - is impossible.

Comment: if i follow the Cloudflare technique would that conceivably solve the issue though?

Comment: @Dog: this should solve the issue since Cloudflare will use a certificate matching your hostname if you use their SSL products like Free SSL.